# LINQ group by and getting latest value

Tags: .net, linq

Say I have a structure like:

```
class SomeObject
   Public Name as String
   Public Created as Date
   ...
end class
```

I have a List(of SomeObject), which has multiple entries for each name with different times. I'd like to select the newest (largest Created value) object for each Name.

Given:

```
Name   Created
A      2010-04-16     *
A      2010-04-15
B      2010-04-12
B      2010-04-13     *
C      2010-04-16     *
```

I'd like to pick the objects with the * beside them.

Is this possible using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:

```
var maxObjects =
    from o in myList
    group o by o.Name into g
    select new { Name = g.Key, Created = g.Max(o => o.Created) };
```

See [101 Linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) to see how Linq can be used.