# Getting the latest entry of each user in LINQ to Entities in a strongly-typed manner

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a database of users and their check-ins in different places with timestamps, related with a foreign key. A user can check-in any time, and can have arbitrary number of entries. I need a LINQ-to-Entities query that will return the checkins in the database, but return only the latest check-in for each user. I am not really a master of SQL or LINQ grouping, I think I need to group the entries. I've seen [LINQ group by and getting latest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657421/linq-group-by-and-getting-latest-value). There is an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657436/811405) that returns what I'm trying to get, but it returns an anonymous class. Is there any way to return the instances of my class in a strongly typed manner without selecting an anonymous class?

**UPDATE:**

I already have this class:

```
public partial class LocationUpdate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Position { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this query:

```
IQueryable<LocationUpdate> nearbyUserLocations = [some LINQ-to-Entities query];
```

I want, just below that line, a query like this:

```
nearbyUserLocations = [collection of each user's latest location update];
```

I need it still in the type of `IQueryable<LocationUpdate>`, **not** some anonymous type.

Comment: users can check-in any time they like, but can they ever leave? (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - if I am reading your question correctly, from your example - instead of doing:

```
var maxObjects =
    from o in myList
    group o by o.Name into g
    select new { Name = g.Key, Created = g.Max(o => o.Created) };
```

try doing:

```
var maxObjects =
    from o in myList
    group o by o.Name into g
    select new MyClass{ Name = g.Key, Created = g.Max(o => o.Created) };
```

and if you want queryable

```
maxObjects.AsQueryable<MyClass>();
```

Assuming that MyClass has public properties Name and Created.

**Edit after further information**

Here is a testable query...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<LocationUpdate> locationUpdates =
            new List<LocationUpdate>
            {
                new LocationUpdate {UserID = 1, Position = 2},
                new LocationUpdate {UserID = 1, Position = 3},
                new LocationUpdate {UserID = 2, Position = 1},
                new LocationUpdate {UserID = 2, Position = 2},
                new LocationUpdate {UserID = 1, Position = 4},
                new LocationUpdate {UserID = 3, Position = 1}
            };

        IEnumerable<Tuple<int, List<MyClass>>> result = locationUpdates.GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
            .Select(x => new Tuple<int, List<MyClass>>(x.Key,
                x.Select(y => new MyClass {Position = y.Position, UserID = y.UserID}).ToList()));

        foreach (Tuple<int, List<MyClass>> tuple in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User {0}", tuple.Item1);

            foreach (MyClass myClass in tuple.Item2)
                Console.WriteLine("User {0}, Position {1}", myClass.UserID, myClass.Position);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

    }

    public class LocationUpdate
    {
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Obviously I have left some of the extra  properties off as they were just noise, but you should just be able to add them in the block of code which creates a new MyClass...

You can still make the result queryable - the result contains a grouping which may not be exactly what you were expecting - I think that maybe this result type will fit your needs though, and maybe that's why you couldn't get a suitable Linq query to get you data.

Whether or not it answers your question, I hope this helps!

Comment: yes, that is what I want, but I'm stuck as I also have other properties in my `MyClass`, that I also want to include. how can I achieve that, e.g. `select new MyClass{ Name = g.Key, Created = g.Max(o => o.Created), MyOtherProperty = ??? };`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you can use he object initializer (as I have done in my example) or add a constructor that takes those extra properties... It's impossible to say without seeing what you have in your implementation of 'myList', or the actual query itself. What the grouping returns is pretty much a key/value pair where the value is an IEnumerable of objects from your list. You may need to break this down a bit to get MyClass... Can you post more about the data you are getting back and what you want to see populated in MyClass?

Comment: I've added my actual classes to the question.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I have added code from a test project I used which is loosely based on the information you have posted. You can always order the list of MyClasses if you want - but best to get it working first I think...! I've used a tuple to hold the key value pair, but you can use a straight keyValue pair if you like instead.

Comment: I'm not the master of this but wouldn't those nested enumerations mean either:
all the checkins are loaded for each users OR it will roundtrip to the database in each iteration?